# Unregister, remove or delete users from Yodlee's private enviroment

Tags: yodlee

I have some users in the private envirtoment that Yodlee provides, and would like to unregister, remove or delete them. Is this possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use uregister API which Yodlee provides to remove an user.

If using SOAP - UserRegistration.unregister(UserContext userContext)

IF using REST - https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/unregister